# Reflexive, Symmetric and Transitive

Tags: logic

I am trying to answer the following question:

R, S, T: 0...10 ⟺ 0...10

R= {m,n:N∥m≠n∧m+n=8}

S= {r:R∥r.1 < r.2}

T=R;S

Give the reflexive, symmetric and transitive closures for R, S and T

For R I have:
R = {(0,8),(1,7),(2,6),(3,5),(5,3),(6,2),(1,7),(8,0)}

Therefore Reflexive Closure: 
R∪{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9),(10,10)}

Symmetric Closure: 
{(0,8),(1,7),(2,6),(3,5),(5,3),(6,2),(7,1),(8,0)}

Transitive Closure: 
R∪{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8)}

Now, I am trying to establish the same for S and T which are based on R

For S, I have:

S = {(0,8),(1,7),(2,6),(3,5)}

Reflexive Closure:
SU{(0,0),(1.1),(2.2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9),(10,10)}

{(0,8),(1,7),(2,6),(3,5),(5,3),(6,2),(7,1),(8,0),(0,0),(1.1),(2.2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9),(10,10)}

Symmetric Closure:
{(0,8),(1,7),(2,6),(3,5),(5,3),(6,2),(7,1),(8,0)}

Transitive Closure:
{(0,8),(1,7),(2,6),(3,5)}

Can you please let me know if this is correct so far. Also, what do you think the outcome for T would be?

Comment: What do you mean with "R, S, T: 0...10 ⟺ 0...10"?

Comment: Its a three pronged question. i.e.:
R:0..10⟺0..10
R={m,n:N∥m≠n∧m+n=8}

S:0..10⟺0..10
S= {r:R∥r.1 < r.2}

T:0..10⟺0..10
T=R;S

Comment: I don't understand the definiton of T ... Also, to show your work, cN you pleas just tell us what you have for $R$, $S$, and $T$ before prociding any kind of closure?

Comment: I've never seen the notation "0...10 ⟺ 0...10", but I suppose that it means "relation between $\{ 0, \ldots, 10 \}$ and $\{ 0, \ldots, 10 \}$".

Comment: Is $T$ the composition of $R$ and $S$, i.e. $xTy$ if there exists $z$ such that $xRz$ and $zSy$?

Comment: T=R;S
the symbol ; is like a 9 with a o on top of it

Comment: @KingGeorge And what does that mean? Do you know?

Comment: Relational composition operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any clsure (whether reflexive, symmetric, or transitive) will have to contain the relation itself ... You are only indicating the pairs that are being added.

Also, I think $S$ is defined as those pars from $R$ where the first number of the pair is smaller han the second.  You must have interpreted it differently, otherwise you would not be adding elements like $(1,2)$ or $(3,6)$ to the symmetric closure of $S$

$T$ should be the composition of $R$ and $T$, so this should contain all $(a,c)$ such that there is some $b$ such that $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in S$. For example, since $(8,0) \in R$, and $(0,8) \in S$, $(8,8) \in T$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I definitely interpreted incorrectly.

In other words you're saying it should be: 
{(0,8),(1.7),(2,6),(3,5)}

Comment: @KingGeorge Exactly!  I see you updated your post, and your $R$ and $S$ are correct. Also, your closures are all correct as well, except for the reflexive closure of $S$, which should be $S$ together with $(0,0),(1,1)$, etc. Note that the symmetric closure of $R$ is $R$ itself, since $R$ is symmetric already. let me see if I can help you out with $T$...

Comment: @KingGeorge OK, that weird semicolon-like symbol is indeed for relational composition ... See the Wikipedia article on Composition of Relations. in my Answer I explain what this means, and give an example of what you should be putting into $T$ ... Can you now figure out $T$?

Comment: Thanks for this. you are right, I have now updated my reflexive closure for S. I think I repeated the elements of S by accident

Comment: @KingGeorge OK, that looks good, though I am not sure what that set is that is listed between the reflexive closure of $S$ and the symmetric closure of $S$.  Note that the symmetric closure of $S$ is $R$.   Have you made any progress on $T$?

Comment: Regarding the set between the reflexive closure of S and the symmetric closure of S I just wrote it all out in full.

I am looking at the article on Wikipedia, can you please send a link so I am sure I am looking at the exact one you are referring to.
However, I think elements of T are: {(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8)}
Please let me know if this is accurate

Comment: @KingGeorge I haven't yet figured out how to create live links on my device ... :(. But yes, your $T$ is correct!

Comment: Thanks. 
Will I also be right in saying the Reflexive closure of T = T
Also, what do you suggest the symmetric and transitive closures of T will be?

Comment: @KingGeorge No. Like $R$ and $S$, you have to include *all* pairs $(x,x)$ with $x$ ranging from $0$ to $10$.  For the other two: you found them for $R$ and $S$ ... let's see if you can find them for $T$ .. I am sure you can do it!

Comment: Sorry, dont know what I was thinking.
Reflexive closure should be:
TU{(0,0),(1.1),(2.2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9),(10,10)}

Comment: Will the Symmetric closure of T= T since it already maps to itself?
i.e. {(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8)}

Comment: @KingGeorge Yes, correct!!

Comment: @KingGeorge And by the way ... That is a very common and understandable mistake you made with the reflexive closure ... Since $T$ only includes pairs containing the numbers 5,6,7,8, you are unlikely to think of all the other numbers that are in the domain. :)

Comment: Fab! Thanks a lot for your patience and guidance. 
I'm not sure what the Transitive closure will be, although I suspect it is T

Comment: @KingGeorge Yes, correct again! The transitive closure of $T$ is just $T$:  The only time you have $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ in $T$ is when $a=b=c$, those being 5,6,7, or 8. So, when you add $(a,c)$, you add either $(5,5)$, $(6,6)$, $(7,7)$, or $(8,8)$, but you already have those, so there are no new pairs to add!  All right, all done, and good job!

Comment: Thanks a whole lot @Bram28 you're the real MVP!
In presenting my answers do I need any type of proof/explanation for all of my closures

Comment: @KingGeorge Depends on your audience and what the instructions were. I can't tell from your post.  But I would say: if in doubt, yes, provide a short explanation.

Comment: @KingGeorge Also, since you're new ... if my 'Answer' (help, really) was satisfactory, you can accept my Answer by clicking on the check mark on the left of it.   Glad I could help!